# PDO Library not detected (classes not found) PHP

Tags: php, composer-php, php-7.4

I'm doing my own website and i'm using a PDO library [here](https://github.com/FaaPz/PDO). I have somes library working fine but this one for any reason cannot be "detected"

Files in the folder:

- Installed lib using composer => /main/assets/
- File where i want to use the lib => /main/user/index.php
- Lib path => /main/assets/vendor/faapz/pdo/...

Reproduce this:

1: In a folder (main), create another folder named "assets", then execute the command "composer require faapz/pdo" (this require an installation of [composer](https://getcomposer.org/))

2: In the folder (main), create folder named "user" and create new php file.

3: Use this code

```
<?php
// => Class 'FaaPz\PDO\Database' not found in ...\main\user\file.php on line 10
$parent_dir = dirname(__DIR__);
require $parent_dir . '/assets/vendor/autoload.php';
$db = new \PDO('mysql:dbname=your_db_name;host=your_db_host;charset=utf8mb4', 'root', ''); // Working lib

$query = 'mysql:host=your_db_host;dbname=your_db_name;charset=utf8';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';

$database = new FaaPz\PDO\Database($query, $user, $pass); // Not working lib => Class 'FaaPz\PDO\Database' not found in ...\main\user\file.php on line 10

$auth = new \Delight\Auth\Auth($db); // Working lib
?>
```

Comment: I guess it's not enabled/installed on your system, you will need the PDO extension for it to work. Also your setup is strange, vendor should be at the root of your project, not in a subfolder

Comment: And also, you don't need `dirname()`, simply : `require __DIR__.'assets/vendor/autoload.php';`

Comment: @Lk77, the vendor folder is up one compared to what appears to be the web root

Comment: @StuckDuck, echo out `$parent_dir . '/assets/vendor/autoload.php'` and make sure that path matches your file system

Answer (score 0):

I found the package "ext-pdo" work for my problem. Just install it using composer with the following command => **composer require ext-pdo**